# Products Price Comparison Tool: Difficulty in matching identical items

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, information-retrieval, cosine-similarity

I'm working on creating an e-comm products price comparison tool(in python) which is somewhat similar to [camelcamelcamel.com](http://camelcamelcamel.com), both for fun and profit. I'm facing the difficult when I want to match the identical items from the list that I gathered from various websites using a search term. I'm using *Cosine similarity* and thinking of using *Levenshtein*'s Algorithm for product matching, to match the titles of the various items against each other to find the identical items.

For example, I have the following items and their price values as,

```
{
    product_0: {
        title: "Apple MacBook Air MMGF2HN/A 13.3-inch Laptop (Core i5/8GB/128GB/Mac OS X/Integrated Graphics)",
        price: "xxxx",
    },
    product_1: {
        title: "Apple MacBook Air MMGF2HN/A 13.3-inch Laptop (Core i5/8GB/128GB/Mac OS X/Integrated Graphics) cover",
        price: "xyzy"
    },
    product_2: {
        title: "Apple Macbook Air MMGF2HNA Notebook (Intel Core i5- 8GB RAM- 128GB SSD- 33.78 cm(13.3)- OS X El Capitan) (Silver)"
        price: "xxyy"
    },
    product_3: {
        title: "....",
        price: "...."
    },

    ...

    product_99: {
        // product title and price
    }

}
```

When I used cosine similarity on the above list(data) of items, the values are as follows

```
cosine(product_0 * product_1) = 0.973328526785
cosine(product_0 * product_2) = 0.50251890763
```

But in reality `product_0` and `product_1` are two different items but their consine similarity value shows that the items are identical; and `product_0` and `product_2` are from same entity but their cosine value shows that they are two different items.

I've been struggling to solve this problem on my own, thought I could ask for some suggestion/advice here in stackoverflow. Am I in the right direction using cosine similarity to match the similarities of items?. If not could you please channel me in the right direction.

My basic idea is to do a price comparison on identical items, i.e., Semantic Analysis of various similar product items.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could train [word2vec](https://code.google.com/archive/p/word2vec/) on the product titles. Resulting code would look something like this when using [the Python word2vec wrapper](https://github.com/danielfrg/word2vec) and slightly different but similar when using [Gensim's model.word2vec](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html):

```
indexes, metrics = model.cosine(normalized_phrase)
model.generate_response(indexes, metrics)
```

The generated response will be the title vectors sorted by descending cosine similarity.

Comment: That's a good idea, perhaps I should start training my model instead of calculating cosine similarity individually. Thanks for the suggestion. I may add description to the title as well, I think I should look at [doc2vec](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/doc2vec.html).